# Canvas cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

setInterval(function (evt) {
    if (frame < 4) {
        frame += 1;
    } else {
        frame = 0;
    }
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    // ...
}, 500);
```

Hello I am new to jQuery/JavaScript, why does `evt.clientX` throws

> cannot read property of undefined

?

Comment: The callback of `setInterval` doesn't get passed any argument, so `evt` is `undefined`.

Comment: How do I pass the evt argument?

Comment: The actual problem is not *how* but rather *what/which*. Event objects are created when an event occurs. The timeout is not an event. Moving the mouse, clicking somewhere, pressing a key, these are all events which create an event object whose properties you can access. But simply calling a function does not give you an event object. So, what are you actually trying to achieve? Which problem are you trying to solve with the timeout?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to poll for the mouse position every 500 ms? Do you have any event listeners bound in your code?  I don't think you can get the mouse position outside of an event.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will capture the evt argument:

```
var test;
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    test = evt;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

setInterval(function (test) {
    if (frame < 4) {
        frame += 1;
    } else {
        frame = 0;
    }
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, test);
    // ...
}, 500);
```

****EDIT****
This code is completely incorrect, try reading this : [How to determine mouse position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

Comment: That's the same problem. `test` will be `undefined`. Changing the variable name or using global variables does not make a difference.

Comment: I tested this in firebug and it logged the event in the console but I'm probably doing some different then. I'll look at it again. And I see the nature ofthe problem after seeing your comment, mhm.

Comment: For this to work, `setInterval(function (test) {` should really be `setInterval(function () {`

Comment: @UselessIntern: What event?  How is your "event" being triggered?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: This is true I see that now, no event is being triggered.

Comment: Is there any way to add an event listener for a step event then? (e.g. trigger it every possible time)

Comment: @user2279927: There is no `step` event. If you want to get the mouse position at each step, you have to keep track of the mouse position independently.

Answer (score 0):

The callback of `setInterval` does not get passed any arguments, so `evt` is `undefined`.

You need to change your code to this:

```
function getMousePos(evt, canvas) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(evt, canvas)
    // ...
})
```

`canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ...)` is a function that runs whenever  the mouse moves over the canvas, and it gets passed the event.

> **Note:** Make sure that `canvas` is defined.